# Automatically run a command upon entering a certain directory?

Tags: 10.10, bash

I'm using [virtualenv](/questions/tagged/virtualenv) with [django](/questions/tagged/django) and so I have say two different directories say:

```
~/Development/site1
~/Development/site2
```

So to set up my enviroment I normally go to `~/Development/site1` then run `source bin/activate`. Is it possible to have that command run automatically when I cd into one of these directories?

Comment: See this recent U&L question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21363/execute-bash-scripts-on-entering-a-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put this in your .bashrc to redefine the "cd" command:

```
cd()
{
    [ -z "$*" ] && builtin cd $HOME
    [ -n "$*" ] && builtin cd "$*"
    [ -f "./bin/activate" && source ./bin/activate
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Would a bash alias suffice? or does it have to be linked to entering the specific directory?

My solution to bash alias.

In ~/.bashrc check that .bash_aliases is ran.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

In ~/.bash_aliases

```
alias siteone='cd ~/Development/site1 && source bin/activate'
alias sitetwo='cd ~/Development/site2 && source bin/activate'
```

Comment: I'll end up doing this instead I think, thanks. I accepted  @user25618 answers because it's more correct for the question.